# How to open a new window below a split created by vimdiff?

Tags: vim, split, text-editor, vimdiff

If, at a command prompt, I run

```
vimdiff file1 file2
```

I get a vim instance that has two files open side-by-side, something like this:

```
╔═══════╤═══════╗
║       │       ║
║       │       ║
║ file1 │ file2 ║
║       │       ║
║       │       ║
╚═══════╧═══════╝
```

This is very nice, but sometimes I want to open a third file to look at. I don't want to create another vertical split, because otherwise the lines will be so short I'd be scrolling horizontally all the time just to read them. But occupying a few lines at the bottom of the screen wouldn't hurt. So, how can I go from the above to the following:

```
╔═══════╤═══════╗
║       │       ║
║ file1 │ file2 ║
║       │       ║
╟───────┴───────╢
║     file3     ║
╚═══════════════╝
```

I've tried using `:sp file3`, but I just end up with this (supposing I ran the command while the cursor was in file1):

```
╔═══════╤═══════╗
║ file3 │       ║
║       │       ║
╟───────┤ file2 ║
║ file1 │       ║
║       │       ║
╚═══════╧═══════╝
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: +1. The internet needs more ASCII art.

Comment: How did you get the ASCII art around the file names?

Comment: @wcm, by copying & pasting the relevant characters in from Character Map in Windows.

Comment: My coworker found a site that tells a bunch about this kind of thing.  Here you go:  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/box_drawing/index.htm

Comment: Examples: ╔ = alt-201, ╚ = alt-200, ╗ = alt-187, ╝ = alt-188

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
:botright split
```

and open a new file inside.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @fgm's answer, If you type this command, you can auto complete the
file name you want to edit like in a normal `:edit`:

```
:bot split +edit thirdfile.cpp
```

But to avoid having to type all that, you can create a *"User defined command"* 
like this:

```
:command -complete=file -nargs=* Third bot split +edit <args>
```

Now you can just type `:Third` to create the third window at the bottom of the
screen with the file you want to edit, for example:

```
:Third mythirdfile.cpp
```

Notice that you can auto complete just like with a normal `:edit`.

And of course you can change the name of the command to something else if you
don't like `:Third`, just keep in mind that it must start with a capital letter.

For more info type `:help user-commands` and `:help 40.2`

Comment: And of course, to have your defined command permanent, put it on your .vimrc file, leaving out the colon (:).

Answer (score 3):

If you've already opened `:sp file3` as in your last example `^WJ` will move an existing window where you want it to go.